# passing variable data to non-activity classes

Tags: java, android

What is the best way to pass variable data from an `Activty` to a `non-Activty` class? The data is created within the `onCreate` of the first `Acivity` I need to pass that data to the second class without the use of Intent. Any code samples would be appreciated.

Since I got it to work like I intended it to  post what I have. In my case I already had a `Constructor` that was an `ArrayList` and for what I was doing I needed another one of the same type. So here goes:

ClassActivity

```
public class Polygon extends Overlay {
ArrayList<GeoPoint> geoPoints;

public Polygon(ArrayList<GeoPoint> points){
    geoPoints = points;
}

public class Hex{
    public Hex(ArrayList<String> str) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     Log.i("string",str.toString());
    }
  }
```

and My main Actvity has

```
 Polygon main = new Polygon(null);
 Polygon.Hex mMainClass = (main.new Hex(color));
```

Note that I had to create an instance of the main class before

```
Polygon.Hex mMainClass = (main.new Hex(color));
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a very basic programming question. Not fit for SO. Unless u have tried something and it does not work.

Comment: Yeah I know it's basic, isn't SO for questions that you can't figure out. If you can't offer a solution why leave a comment. You wasted 10 seconds of your life typing a non beneficial response.

Comment: I observed that, the questions asking like **"What is the best way?"** are normally closed by the SO community, So please try to post the relevant code what you have tried so far and where you getting stuck,so you will get more help for community, hope you got me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Class Name is `MainClass` then Create `Constructor` for that and pass value as a parameter, below is a example for that.

MainClass.java

```
public class MainClass {
    public MainClass(int i, String str) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }
}
```

Use below code for Pass Value from MainActivity to MainClass, Here `i` is integer variable and `str` is a String variable

```
MainClass mMainClass = new MainClass(i, str);
```

Comment: Thank You very much for you answer!! This solved my problem. I was close but I had the constructors name wrong on the mainActivities side.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class object in that activity class.

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.yourVariable = "Your Value";
```